# How can I edit/remove my pictures in Android -devices on desktop?

Tags: camera, images, photos, picasa, editing

I want to remove a bunch of images and it is extremely slow in Android. I want to edit things directly in Desktop, maybe such services with something like Google Picasa (?). In other words, how can I edit my images on the memory card of the Android device on Desktop?

The Desktop and the Android are linked with the same Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via WiFi, using a remote management app like e.g. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) or, when on Windows, [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client). There are a lot more apps like this, and they give you the added benefit of being able to manage a lot of other things remotely -- as e.g. reading/writing SMS, managing apps/contacts/ringtones, copying files between your device and your computer, and sometimes even backup stuff.

Most of them (like the mentioned *AirDroid<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjESJ.jpg)</sup>*) start a web service on your device, which you then can access with your browser. This often looks like a "virtual PC" (see screenshot below). Others (like here *MyPhoneExplorer<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfVet.jpg)</sup>*) have a native PC-Client, which can even do more (like here: synchronizing with Outlook and others).

[image: AirDroid]

*AirDroid* managing pictures

[image: MyPhoneExplorer]

*MyPhoneExplorer* Windows Client

Comment: can you tell me Py phone Explorer is developed in which Technology ?

Comment: @RahulGupta No. I don't use Windows, so I neither use this app. Apart from that, this is a completely different question, and not quite fitting on this site; better check [their home page](http://www.fjsoft.at/) for details, or contact their developers.